# How to read non multipart form-data content with aiohttp

Tags: python, aiohttp

Given a response such as:

```
--f66def0c5e644c17a1c35c36067512ab
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="media"; filename="media"
Content-Length: 5

hello
--f66def0c5e644c17a1c35c36067512ab--
```

How is it supposed to be read with aiohttp. I got no trouble reading `multipart/form-data` response using a `MultipartReader` but it fails in this case with the error:

```
async with self.session.get(url, ssl=self.ssl_context, headers=headers) as response:
    if response.status != 200:
        await self._handle_http_error(response)
    
    # very basic attempt to get the only part form-data
    reader = MultipartReader.from_response(response)
    part = await reader.next()
    return await part.read()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
  File "/home/rdebroize/.virtualenvs/pyms/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/multipart.py", line 569, in from_response
    response, cls(response.headers, response.content)
  File "/home/rdebroize/.virtualenvs/pyms/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/multipart.py", line 537, in __init__
    self._boundary = ("--" + self._get_boundary()).encode()
  File "/home/rdebroize/.virtualenvs/pyms/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/multipart.py", line 633, in _get_boundary
    assert mimetype.type == "multipart", "multipart/* content type expected"
AssertionError: multipart/* content type expected
```

Comment: Can you provide some code to test?

Comment: @rikyeah I added an example of what I did. this won't you allow to test it though, I don't know any public url returnins such responses. In my case it comes from an internal service trying to moke an S3 instance.